# Help in understanding how general relativity describes space-time near black hole poles that emit astrophysical jets

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, astrophysics, relativistic-jets

I am aware that General relativity does not explicitly deal with 'expanding' or growing and due to that reason 'cosmologically pressurised' aether (proposed by the 'Theory of a river flow' but that can be also compared to the standard model theory that propose it as a result of the action of dark energy as we know that the Universe is expanding which should be accompained with cosmological pressure... ) that is moving towards the black hole center as towards a sink (causing gravitational effect) and possible ejection of that same aether at the poles maybe due to less 'cosmological pressure' at the poles. This could somehow explain why particles may win against the strong gravitational force of the BH and leave the space near it even they cannot reach a speed greater than the speed of light.This all pressumtions that are interesting can be easely contested... But is then GR proposing something why the space-time curvature is differently deformed in that special case of the poles of the BH emitting astrophysical jets?

Comment: Jets are associated with accretion disks: no black hole is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Relativistic jets observed in quasars (and other black holes) are not fully understood, but there is consensus around the basics.  Matter falls towards a rotating black hole from an [accretion disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_disk).  Some of the infalling matter follows a near-miss trajectory that enters the black hole's [ergosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergosphere), but does not cross the event horizon.  This matter can be greatly boosted in speed thanks to the [Penrose process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_process), which effectively converts some of the black hole's rotational energy to linear kinetic energy of the matter.

This basic description is called the [Blandford-Znajek process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blandford%E2%80%93Znajek_process) and was first described in 1977.  An important piece of the puzzle glossed over above is the effect of the magnetic field of the accretion disk.  The magnetic field in important for funneling the matter into the narrow jets at the black hole's poles.  The original work doesn't cover all of the messy details, but puts the basic idea in place.

The full physical description will involve the complicated interactions of general relativity, nuclear matter, and electromagnetic fields.  This [review by Blandford, Meier, and Readhead](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-astro-081817-051948) ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.06025)) is a good place to start digging in.

The physics is complicated, but there is no "cosmological pressure" or other exotic physics needed to explain what is happening in a relativistic jet.